# Yii gridview pagination custom event click

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I'm using CGridView to display grid data, include pagination. When I click on a page, ajax request is called and update result to the gird. But I want it do other thing when I click on a page.
Here is my code :

```
 $('#myGridID .pagination li a').live('click', function (e) {

    //I want do something here
    return false; // I don't want pagination call default method, but it not work
});
```

Although I return false in the function, but ajax update still called.
Do you have any solutions for this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

use stopPropagation of event's object

```
$('#myGridID .pagination li a').live('click', function (e) {

    //I want do something here
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Also you can just turn it off in Yii (Tokens are available from 1.1.11)

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    ...
    'updateSelector' => '{sort}',
    ...
));
```

Comment: I also try `e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;` but not work :(

Comment: I think event of CGridView sets before your code. Try set up your code before init CGridView

Comment: I resolved my prob by another way, thanks so much for your response. Good luck